# Convert pdf file to html file using php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i want to convert PDF uploaded by user to HTML file and shown on browser. 
   so for that is there any simple solution in php , jquery or js.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

the supporting software is available, you can use that one:

**1.** download and unpack the .exe file to a folder: [PDFtoHTML](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdftohtml/)

**2.** Create a .php file, & put this code (assuming, that `pdftohtml.exe` is inside that folder, and the source `test.pdf` as well)

```
<?php
$source_pdf="test.pdf";
$output_folder="MyFolder";

if (!file_exists($output_folder)) { mkdir($output_folder, 0777, true);}
$a= passthru("pdftohtml $source_pdf $output_folder/new_file_name",$b);
var_dump($a);
?>
```

**3.** enter MyFolder, and you'll see the converted files

Comment: i already tried this but it is not accurate.there is a bug in it. it is taking physical path for images so that images are not displaying.

Comment: you can use `indexOf("img_path")` to avoid path from root

Comment: where and how to user 'indexof'? please help because i didnt find any 
 
indexof() function in php

Comment: its not `php` prperty, you have to do it with `javascript`

Comment: ok So where to put this code every time a new html file is generating?